# How can we speed up a matrix multiplication using ParallelTable and ParallelISum?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, parallelization, summation

I do belive that Mathematica can work as fast as other packages, but it is really sensitive to the way we write the code. Here I would like to evaluate a trace resulted from a matrix multiplication at many points as follwos

```
KS[x_, y_,z_] := {{0, I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 
    13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y] - Cos[z] - I Sin[z], -1}, {-I Sin[x] + 
     Sin[y], 0, -1, 
    13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y] - Cos[z] - I Sin[z]}, {13/4 - Cos[x] - 
     Cos[y] - Cos[z] + I Sin[z], -1, 0, -I Sin[x] - Sin[y]}, {-1, 
    13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y] - Cos[z] + I Sin[z], I Sin[x] - Sin[y], 0}};
Oz[x_, y_,z_] :=
  {{0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-Cos[z] - I Sin[z])}, {0, 0, 
    1/2 (Cos[z] + I Sin[z]), 0}, {0, 1/2 (Cos[z] - I Sin[z]), 0, 
    0}, {1/2 I (I Cos[z] + Sin[z]), 0, 0, 0}};
Ox[x_, y_,z_] := {{0, I Cos[x], Sin[x], 0}, {-I Cos[x], 0, 0, 
    Sin[x]}, {Sin[x], 0, 0, -I Cos[x]}, {0, Sin[x], I Cos[x], 0}};
F2[x_, y_, z_, 
   r_] := (Inverse[(r + I*0.01)*IdentityMatrix[4] - KS[x, y, z]]);
F1[x_, y_, z_, 
   r_] := (Inverse[(r - I*0.01)*IdentityMatrix[4] - KS[x, y, z]]);
Myfun[x_, y_, z_, r_] := 
  Re[Tr[(Ox[x, y, z].(F2[x, y, z, r] - F1[x, y, z, r]).Oz[x, y, 
       z].(F2[x, y, z, r].F2[x, y, z, r] + 
        F1[x, y, z, r].F1[x, y, z, r]))]];
```

Then I used `ParallelSum` with `Table` to do the job, but it is very slow> Is there any way to speed it up?

```
nr=5;nc=9;
Table[ParallelSum[(nc/(2\[Pi]))^-3 1/nr Myfun[x,y,z,r],{r,-7.25,R,1/nr},{x,\[Pi]/nc,\[Pi],(2\[Pi])/nc},
{y,\[Pi]/nc,\[Pi],(2\[Pi])/nc},{z,\[Pi]/nc,\[Pi],(2\[Pi])/nc}],{R,-1,1,0.5}]//AbsoluteTiming
    {9.9159,{1.64289,-1.40237,-1.40319,-1.40314,0.10968}}
```

I want to do it with `nr=100` and `nc=200`.

Comment: (1) Use `nr = 5.; nc = 9.;` in other words, use inexact values for nr and nc (2)  let `Parallelize` choose the best approach by doing `Parallelize[Table[Sum[...`. This brings it down to 2.4s on my machine. (3) Eliminate some repeated calculations of F1 and F2 in `Myfun` by doing `Myfun[x_, y_, z_, r_] := Block[{f1 = F1[x, y, z, r], f2 = F2[x, y, z, r]}, Re[Tr[(Ox[x, y, z].(f2 - f1).Oz[x, y, z].(f2.f2 + f1.f1))]]];` This cuts it down to just over a second.

Comment: I can get it a little lower to 0.8 seconds, if I remove F1 and F2 and roll them into a single function to reduce recalculation of KS, as `F1F2[x_, y_, z_, r_] := 
 Block[{ks = KS[x, y, z], id = IdentityMatrix[4]}, {(Inverse[(r - I*0.01)*id - ks]), (Inverse[(r + I*0.01)*id -ks])}]` then `Myfun[x_, y_, z_, r_] := Block[{f = F1F2[x, y, z, r]}, Re[Tr[(Ox[x, y, z].(f[[2]] - f[[1]]).Oz[x, y, z].(f[[2]].f[[2]] + f[[1]].f[[1]]))]]];` then apply (1) and (2) from my previous comment.

Comment: @flinty I would really appreciate if you can post it as an answer please so I can also accept it?

Comment: Is 0.08 seconds on a couple year old laptop sufficiently quick?

Comment: @ciao, how did you do it, the results I posted were performed with a  workstation with 20 core and 120G as RAM-:) So, 0.08 sec would be AWESOME

Comment: @flinty, with redefining F1F2 it went down to 1 sec, but when replace the parallelization with step (2) it goes to 2.4 sec?

Comment: @ciao, may you please show me how to improve the speed by 100 factor?

Comment: @HD2006 : happy to. Just landed and will be away on trip and away from machine for a few days, will post on return if you've not seen a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @ciao, I will be waiting:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile your function to speed up the evaluation:

```
MyfunCompiled = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}, {r, _Real}},
    Evaluate@Re[Tr[(Ox[x, y, z].(F2[x, y, z, r] - F1[x, y, z, r]).Oz[x, y, z].
        (F2[x, y, z, r].F2[x, y, z, r] + F1[x, y, z, r].F1[x, y, z, r]))]], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"];

nr = 5; nc = 9;
AbsoluteTiming@Sum[(nc/(2 \[Pi]))^-3 1/nr Myfun[x, y, z, r], 
    {r, -7.25, 1, 1/nr}, {x, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {y, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {z, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}]

AbsoluteTiming@Sum[(nc/(2 \[Pi]))^-3 1/nr MyfunCompiled[x, y, z, r], 
    {r, -7.25, 1, 1/nr}, {x, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {y, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {z, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}]
```

> ```
> {4.8844, 0.10968}
> {0.050282, 0.10968}
> ```

For further improvements, you can also compile the actual sum:

```
FunSum = Compile[{{R, _Real}, {nr, _Integer}, {nc, _Integer}},
  Sum[(nc/(2π))^-3 1/nr MyfunCompiled[x, y, z, r], 
    {r, -7.25, 1, 1/nr}, {x, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {y, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}, {z, π/nc, π, 2π/nc}]
,CompilationTarget -> "C"];

nr = 5; nc = 9;
AbsoluteTiming@FunSum[1, nr, nc]
```

> ```
> {0.007274, 0.10968}
> ```

Your example would then look like this (following the suggestion of flinty in comments about parallelizing over the different values of `R`):

```
nr = 5; nc = 9;
ParallelTable[FunSum[R, nr, nc], {R, -1, 1, 0.5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.027832, {1.64289, -1.40237, -1.40319, -1.40314, 0.10968}}
> ```

This is now fast enough that you can try going for larger values of `nr` and `nc`. For example:

```
AbsoluteTiming[FunSum[1, 50, 50]]
AbsoluteTiming[FunSum[1, 100, 100]]
AbsoluteTiming[FunSum[1, 100, 200]]
```

> ```
> {5.55616, 0.452771}
> {73.7241, 0.484847}
> {678.142, 0.48616}
> ```

which seems to converge (at least it looks like it does).

Comment: that is Great!, by the way, will it help if we remove F1 and F2 and roll them into a single function to reduce recalculation of KS,as suggested by "flinty" in the comments, and combine it with your approach ?

Comment: It is unfortunately not directly applicable to my method, since I am basically compiling a single, long function, and all the higher-level operations like `Inverse` are precomputed. I did just try a version where I only precompute `F1`, `F2`, `Ox` and `Oz`, and the compiled function then assembles the `Re[Tr[Dot[]]]`, but there is essentially no improvement in the timings.